# HMRC MTD Hello World with Qt

Tags: json, qt, http

I have a Qt program that stores all my small (tiny) company information on a sql database and I have over the years tailored it to do all my accounting stuff, invoices, BOMs etc.

At the push of a button I can get all of the necessary sql data to calculate a quarterly VAT return, but  we're going to have to electronically submit all the data now, not just calculate it. I have all the data needed, it's just a case of submitting over HTTP using json (of which I know a little/nothing about respectively).

I'm small enough so that I don't have to do this submission at the moment, but the time will likely come, so I'm trying the most basic of requests in the HMRC's sandbox as a starting point.

On [this](https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/tutorials) page it shows you how to do an hello world request in Java, so I'm trying to do the same with Qt with C++.

I've tried the following which responds to the push of a button and I have of course, set up a slot to deal with a response:

```
void MainWindow::hello()
{

QJsonObject json;
QString rs("https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world");

QNetworkRequest request
    {
    QUrl(rs)
    };

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json");
request.setUrl(QUrl(rs));
manager->get(request);


}
```

and the main window init:

```
 manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QObject::connect
            (manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, [=](QNetworkReply *reply)
                {
                if (reply->error())
                    {
                    ui->debugText->appendHtml(reply->errorString());                    
                    return;
                    }        
                QString answer = reply->readAll();
                ui->debugText->appendHtml(answer);                
                }
            );
```

To which I get the reply:

> Error transferring https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world -
>   server replied: Not Acceptable

I assume that means I am communicating with the sever now, but I do not know what this terse error message means!

The Java on the HMRC web page is as follows:

```
// construct the GET request for our Hello World endpoint
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
  "https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world");
request.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json");

// execute the request
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

// extract the HTTP status code and response body
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Is that enough information for someone to point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong please? Suspect I am missing a fundamental point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Java example, you are setting the HTTP header "Accept". In your C++/Qt snippet, your are setting the "Content-Type" header.

You may want to adapt your code like this to match your Java working example:

```
QNetworkRequest request { QUrl(rs) };

request.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Accept"), QByteArray("application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json"));
manager->get(request);
```